Spring Boot Images not served over HTTPS
I have a weird error.
I have some images lying in a folder on my server in /media/uploads
I then served these images over a Spring Boot application with this Controller:
@GetMapping("/image/{name}")
    fun getImage(@PathVariable name: String): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
        val path = Paths.get("$PATH/$name")
        val resource = UrlResource(path.toUri())

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(resource)
    }

When using this over http I have no problems at all, but as soon as I enable SSL this endpoint stops working, which means the /image endpoint is not reachable at all over https. All other sites seem to work except they don't load these images.
My application.properties if this helps:
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=/root/foto/certificate.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-password=***
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12

I already tried:

still serving the images over http (but http requests inside https sites get blocked)
serving both http and https

Any ideas would be appreciated

What do you mean with not reachable? Do you get a timeout? An unexpected status code? Can you please include the logs (ideally with TRACE logging if relevant components)?

@dan1st That's the thing I'm not getting an error message. I just get a "This website is unreachable" when trying the endpoint directly in the browser and a "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" in the browser when trying to load an image over this endpoint

name not resolved seems like a DNS (or similar) issue, not something related to the endpoint. Anyways, please make sure you are providing a [mcve].
